# getting variable name which is a argument of the function as a string

Tags: javascript

I know we can get a variable name as a string like this:

```js
const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0]
const someVar = 42
const displayName = varToString({ someVar })
console.log(displayName);
```

But I want to know if there is a solution in JavaScript to get the variable name set as a argument  in a function?

```js
function foo(variable) {

    const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0]
    const displayName = varToString({ variable })
    console.log(displayName);

}

const someVariable = ['string', 'another string'];
foo(someVariable);
```

As you see I get the internal variable name inside the function which is expected here... I want the original variable name instead so in this case we should get `someVariable`.

Is there any solution or I'm just wasting my time?

Comment: Why is the variable name important? Most of the time you *shouldn't* rely on the name of a variable. If you do, it shouldn't be a variable but you should be using an object with keys.

Comment: Essentially this is not possible, and nor should it need to be.

Comment: I think you are wasting your time, and if you actually _need_ this for anything, then I’d say you must be doing something wrong before already. (And what about `foo(5)` or `foo('bar')`, when there would not even _be_ any variable name?)

Comment: *"I know we can get a variable name as a string like this:"* That **doesn't** get a variable name. It gets a property name, which is inferred from a variable name elsewhere in the code.

Comment: `{ variable }` creates an object with `"variable"` as key and the value in `variable` as it's value. Then you get the first key of this object. It's a hack. You'd have to `foo({ someVariable })` to get that variable name to the `foo` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, `varToString()` is called with an object with a named property, and then you can retrieve the property name as you are doing already.

In the second snippet, `foo()` receives an array object without any information about where it came from; that is just how parameter passing works in javascript.
If you change that call to `foo({ someVariable })` then you can make it work again, because then you have created a new object that has a named property.

Answer (score 1):

> I know we can get a variable name as a string like this:

That **doesn't** get a variable name. It gets a property name, which is inferred from a variable name elsewhere in the code.

> But I want to know if there is a solution in JavaScript to get the variable name set as a argument in a function?

No. What's passed to the function is the **value** that came from the variable. There is nothing that connects that value back to the variable.